# asynchronous communication between c++ and c# in the same app

Tags: c#, c++, events, interop, windows-ce

Is there any way I can asynchronously communicate with c# code from c++, in the same process?

I mean that I have to mix managed c# and unmanaged c++ (using pInvoke) in the same WindowsCE based application. The c# part is the core of the application. The c++ part of code has a thread that listens for events and when an event is intercepted I want to have a way to communicate to the c# part that an event was triggered.

For the moment I thought that events are the way for communication between c++ and c#, but is it possible?

Is there a way to do this communication asynchronously?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Communicating asynchronously between C# and C++ is no different to communicating asynchronously between two parts of a C# application- you just end up calling a different function at the end- that is, C#'s `delegate` types will turn into function pointers on the C++ end courtesy of the .NET JIT. This is known as reverse P/Invoke and will allow unmanaged C++ to call in to .NET code.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to use callbacks represented as delegates in managed code and as function pointers in unmanaged code. Here's an MSDN article outlining the approach:

[How to: Pass a Delegate^ to a Native Function Expecting a Function Pointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235575%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: this sounds like C++ CLI which I think is not supported in Windows CE

Comment: @Alina Danila : The code being demonstrated is C++/CLI, but the concept of marshaling a delegate to a native function pointer is language agnostic and is only a slight syntax difference in C#.